# How to render highcharts from column to colum and pie( per catagory)

Tags: javascript, jsp, highcharts

Sorry. I only speak very little English.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luj910d1/)

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Total Work'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017']
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of fruits'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'B1',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'B2',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
        stack: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'B3',
        data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
        stack: 'female'
    }, {
        name: 'B4',
        data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
        stack: 'gay'
    }]
});
```

I want to B1, B2 to column and convert B3, B4 to pie per catagory.

Like this picture:
[image]

Thank for all direction

Answer (score 0):

You need to create five separate series with type of `pie` and set their positions using `center` array.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cpie%3E.center
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.size
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.startAngle

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/czmtqypg/